# (C++) Debugging dll project in release mode (from main project)

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2008

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 C++.

Here's my project list.

- MainProject -> .exe
- Library1 -> .dll
- Library2 -> .dll

I'm trying to debug my project in 'Release Mode' because it takes too long in 'Debug Mode'.

The problem is that, if something wrong happens (ex. Access Violation) in "Library1" while debugging, I can't get through to the DLL.

Is there any way to access the DLL project when debugging 'Release Mode' from the main project? (I think it's related to symbolic problems.)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") should include the desired behavior,  a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it as formatted text in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/26653714)

Comment: Write a loader exe which loads your dll, debug your dll with that loader in VS.

Comment: *I'm trying to debug my project in 'release mode' because it takes too long in 'debug mode'.* -- Just turn off the optimizations in the "Release Mode", turn on the debugging options in the "Release Mode", and rebuild your application.  You now have a release build with debugging information, and you are able to debug it just as if you have a debug build.